# I am trying to remove a few characters from columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

So I have two dataframes, they're supposed to have a column in common, but one of the dataframes has a few characters preventing me from merging them, (DSO).

is there a way to remove an exact string and special characters from a column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the pandas `replace` method to remove the unwanted string from your pandas Series.

For instance:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Character": ["Kenny", "Cartman", "Eric", "Stan"]})
df["Character"].str.replace('Kenny','')
```

EDIT: In your example, I had to use `regex=False` to get rid of the parentheses.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Character": ["(DSO)", "Cartman", "Eric", "Stan"]})
df["Character"].str.replace("(DSO)",'', regex=False)
```

This snippet returned:

```
0           
1    Cartman
2       Eric
3       Stan
Name: Character, dtype: object
```

Comment: I did that, I am stuck with the (), 
 dealer_list['Dealer'] = dealer_list['Dealer'].str.replace('(DSO )','')
I thought this would remove  the whole thing [ (DSO)]

Comment: Then try using the `regex=False` parameter.